# Java, 64-bit, JNI - compared to .NET CLR

Tags: java, 64-bit, java-native-interface

The .NET assembly PE header has a target platform for 32-bit / 64-bit which is used when the assembly use native interop like [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) (otherwise it would be `Target=AnyCPU`).

Is there any equivalent for Java when the Java application has an interface to some native interface through [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)? The JNI has to be either compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit.

Is there an article explaining Java 64-bit architecture and development? I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect 64-bit by using:

```
public static final boolean is64bit = (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").indexOf("64") != -1)
```

You can also start Java in 32 or 64-bit by using `-d32` or `-d64`.

If this for a web or desktop application there may be a way of specifying it from the manifest file.

Comment: That's a Sun-specific and undocumented system property, it might not work on other JVM implementations or on future Oracle Java versions.

Comment: I am not looking to determine what platform I am running on. 
My question is whether I can mark my code that it is not compatible with 32-bit so it wouldn't run on 32-bit Java impl.

Of course this can be manually implemented with your suggested technique

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the system property `os.arch`:

```
String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Unfortunately the possible values for this property are not documented, but you might try it out on different systems to see what it returns (using Sun JDK 6 update 20 on my 64-bit system it returns `amd64`).

See the API documentation of `java.lang.System.getProperties()` for other available system properties.